# How do I get the approvers of a pull request using GitHub Actions / Workflows?

Tags: github-actions, pull-request, github-codereviews

In a GitHub Action.

From all of the reviewers of a pull request

The people who have approved said pull request

I want to get their username.

---

I am expecting there is a value I can pass to a "step" in the workflow. Something like how there is `${{ github.event.pull_request.body }}`

I am wanting to get a value like: `APPROVERS: ${{ github.event.pull_request.reviewers }}` so I can parse it to a custom script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there isn't anything in the default GitHub workflow specification (that I could find), I ended up just making this open-source GitHub Action that will get that info for you:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-github-pull-request-reviews

[image: Screenshot of the Get GitHub Pull Request Reviews action]

Easy as just adding this step into my workflow:

```yaml
- name: Get GitHub Pull Request Reviewers
  id: reviews
  # Versions come from https://github.com/LiamPerson/get-reviews-action/releases
  uses: LiamPerson/get-reviews-action@SPECIFY_ME # Specify the version you want by writing in a tag from the link above. E.g: v1.0
```

Then consuming the result like so:

```yaml
- name: Consumes reviews
  uses: some/workflow@version
  with:
    RELEASES_JSON_FILE: ${{ steps.reviews.outputs.reviews_file_path }} # Note `reviews` is just the id used to identify the step earlier
```

Only thing to be careful of is, this will just give you a **file** with the reviews rather than a **JSON string** as the string is too much to store in the Action variables.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reviewers should be available in the

- `github.event.pull_request.pull_request.requested_reviewers`
- `github.event.pull_request.pull_request.requested_teams`

You can use the GitHub CLI to query the Review Requests:

```
gh pr view https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/pull/6793 --json "reviewRequests,reviews"
```

Comment: Also mentioned under the event payload: https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

Comment: I am looking for the people who have conducted the review rather than the people who were requested. I can see this would be great for the latter, but - my end goal is to get the approvals.